# How to run JS script that is compiled from C

Tags: javascript, c

I need to understand how to run compiled JS script **CORRECTLY** because I got some erorrs.

What I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printNewLines(int amountOfNewLines);

int main() {
   char answerFromUser;

   printf("Hello man, I need you to enter single character. ");
   scanf("%c", &answerFromUser);
   printNewLines(3);
   printf("OMG, you entered: %c", answerFromUser);

   scanf(" %c", &answerFromUser); //To prevent immediate exit
   return 0;
}

void printNewLines(int amountOfNewLines)
{
   for (int newLine = 0; newLine < amountOfNewLines; newLine++)
   {
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

When I compile it to JS and run using Emscripten on WSL, I get this:
[image: warnings]

And when I compile it with `-o file.html` option and try to paste script from JS file to Firefox console I get this:
[image: warnings]

It seems even `scanf()` doesn't work. So, what am I doing wrong and how to compile files properly?

Comment: Please read the warning, it tells you something you should do

Comment: I don't know Emscripten well, so I don't understand what does that error mean. I have all necessary files but it requires magic valid URL.

Comment: Seems like you should use flags as the message highlighted. Did you tried to compile with "-s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=0" flags ?

Comment: @YigitYasar I tried with that option but anyway script skips `scanf()` without warnings when I run node filename.js

Comment: @YigitYasar yeah, I solved that magic thing.

Comment: Great, good job buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all I need to run HTTP server using `node` or something else. Then override `window.prompt` method to handle inputs from user.